# what does <% %> do in c++?

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm using cppimport, which is a library that helps importing cpp into python. As described here: https://github.com/tbenthompson/cppimport, it is necesary to put setup_pybind11 into `/* */` in the cpp file.

```
/*
<%
setup_pybind11(cfg)
%>
*/
```

It appears that when I put it in `/* */` as described in the documentation, then it has no effect when the cpp file is imported from python. However, it all works fine from python when I don't use the `/* */`, but then I can't run it anymore from visual studio. Any suggestions what I can do? Why do I have to remove the `/* */` to work it correctly from python?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is wrapped by `/*` and `*/` so from the C++ side it is a [comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)).

I guess that your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) is running some other program on the same C++ file.

> but then I can't run it anymore from visual studio.

Maybe consider using and configuring some better build automation. Tools like [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [omake](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/omake.html) or the old [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) comes to mind. Of course you would configure them to run the [cppimport](https://github.com/tbenthompson/cppimport) magic (please read its [README](https://github.com/tbenthompson/cppimport/blob/stable/README.md) entirely).

Most C++ compilers are at heart command line driven. Look into [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/). Both exist on Windows (which I never used, since I use Linux).

> it has no effect when the cpp file is imported from python.

But **you don't** ["import"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) it. According to the [README](https://github.com/tbenthompson/cppimport/blob/stable/README.md) you `import cppimport`, not your C++ file:

> Open a python interpreter and run these lines :
>
> ```
> >>> import cppimport
> >>> somecode = cppimport.imp("somecode") #This will pause for a moment to compile the module
> >>> somecode.square(9)
> ```

PS. I am not a native English speaker, and I never used Python (I prefer [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) whose [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) is close to Python's one, with a [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) that is much nicer and cleaner in my opinion, see [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) for more). But when a file is named `README` I am reading it completely.

Comment: works all great now, only issue I have is to get it to work with multiple cpp files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231288/import-multiple-cpp-files-with-pybind11-and-cppimport